# firebase cloud function listing users doesn't return uid of user

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've implemented a function to list all users with the role 'user'. The function returns all the users, however, I would like the uid to be attached to the user to use for restful routing on the client.

```
exports.listUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('role', '==', 'users').get();
  const users = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  response.send(JSON.stringify(users));
});
```

How would I be able to attach the uid to the user objects?

Comment: Where are you storing the UID in the database?  What do your documents look like?

Comment: are u 100% positive that you are saving the uuid on the user's docs? it doesnt happen by default

Comment: Note that this question seems not specific to Cloud Functions, but more related to using Firestore from Node.js. The answer depends on your data structure, so please add a screenshot of a document that you get back from this query, highlighting where you expect the UID to come from.

Comment: I haven't stored the UID manually so I'm assuming it hasn't been stored in the user db

Comment: If the UID isn't stored in the database anywhere, then I think you'll have a hard time surfacing that info.  Are you using the document ID to store the UID?

Comment: Apologies, this is my first project on firebase - users are just created using the standard firebase authentication and haven't added any customisation to store the id in the document - I thought this was handled by firebase auth however it seems it isn't

Comment: Data in Firebase Auth isn't automatically linked to data in Firestore an any way, other than through the code you write.  If you want to store per-user data in Firestore, you'll have to create those doucments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that you use the UID as the document ID. Since the document ID is not part of `document.data()`, it won't be returned with your current code.

The fix is to explicitly add the ID:

```
const users = snapshot.docs.map(doc => { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() });
```

---

In case your document doesn't have an `id` field, you can also merge the ID with the fields, like this:

```
const users = snapshot.docs.map(doc => { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
```

Comment: Did you mean doc.id?